PowerBI report to MS Teams on scale
I've created a report using data from Microsoft Sentinel, which I exported as an M query. I then created an app in the PowerBI workspace that can be published in Microsoft Teams. This is working fine for my tenant.
Now, I would like to publish it on another tenant (and eventually multiple tenants). What is the best way to achieve this? My main concern is how to change the data source so it pulls information from a specific Log Analytics workspace. I want to ensure the report is unique to each environment and its data.
I know I can change the data source in Power BI Desktop and point it to another Log Analytics workspace and then eventually export it to another PowerBI tenant but this method seems cumbersome, especially when scaling up.
Does anyone have experience with this and can share some advice?
Adding new parameters to PowerBI report to easily change Workspace ID and pull data from another tenant.

This scenario involves creating a Power BI workspace for each tenant and using the Power BI REST API to automate the creation of new customer tenants. You can then use semantic models to isolate customer tenants and ensure that users from one tenant don't see data that belongs to another tenan

Create a Power BI workspace for each tenant.
Use the Power BI REST API to automate the creation of new customer tenants.
Use semantic models to isolate customer tenants and ensure that users from one tenant don't see data that belongs to another tenant.
Add new parameters to the Power BI report to easily change the Workspace ID and pull data from another tenant.
